# How to remove blank space in bash script with oracle query

Tags: sql, bash, oracle

I am writing bash script to get list of IDs from 1 table.
example:

```
OracleExec ()
{
OUTPUT=`sqlplus -s "$LOGON" << EOF
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
SET HEADING OFF
SET AUTOCOMMIT ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET LINESIZE 2200
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET COLSEP ""
$SQL_QUERY
EXIT
EOF`
}

    SQL_QUERY="select from id1, id2 form table_a;"
    
    OracleExec

exit 0
```

Once I executed this script I am getting the expected data but with blank spaces like:

```
ID1                        ID1
ID2                        ID2
```

The question is how to remove space between those 2 columns. I am not able to find which SET parameter will allow doing that.
Can you pls advise ?
Thank you

Comment: What result do you want - a single space, or comma-separated; and either way with quotes around individual column values that are string which could themselves include spaces/delimiters?

Comment: I would like to have as results: only 1 space between ID1 ID1.

Comment: Since you want to solve the problem inside SQL, I suggest to remove the bash tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of SQL*Plus you can do:

```
set markup csv on delimiter ' ' quote off
```

That uses a space as a delimiter, and stops it putting double-quotes around string values.

Comment: Does it matter what type the columns have? Say that ID1 is of type char(10) and contains 'AB        ', will it still remove trailing spaces?

Comment: The actual values in the columns will be left as they are, so if you have a string with a trailing space that will still be there; with `char(10)` all the values will be space-padded to 10 characters (except nulls). Unless you apply `trim()`. One of the reasons keeping quotes might be helpful. It's going to be hard to interpret the results if you don't know whether a space is a delimiter or part of a value. If you really want to replace *all* runs of multiple spaces, wherever they come from, with a single space then processing the result set in bash might be easier.

Comment: I found the solution: Addition to parameter: set markup csv on delimiter ' ' quote off I added  SET PAGESIZE 0 which present records with 1 space between. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Usrlnx2, upvote and/or accept the answer. It will help future readers understand what worked

Comment: @Usrlnx2 - `pagesize` won't affect spaces within a row of the result set; it would prevent headings being repeated, but you're already supressing those.